# Escape single quote in adhoc query

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following query:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(
@"SELECT `Customer ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Role` 
  FROM `Contacts` WHERE `Customer ID` = '" + customerID + "'", connection);
```

If a customer ID has an apostrophe within, (i.e. `Adam's Meat`), I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Meat'' at line 1

What is the best way to make this query work?

Comment: I do not have access enough to create stored procedures

Comment: dont use spaces in field or table names then you wouldnt need those silly quotes :P

Answer (score 2):

You should use Parameters instead, this way you also prevent SQL Injection:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT `Customer ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Role` FROM `Contacts` WHERE `Customer ID` = ?CostumerID", connection);
command.Parameters.Add("?CustomerID", customerID);
```